# SQL Server 2005 - Using Null in a comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, comparison, null

This is more of a question to satisfy my own curiosity.  Given the following statement:

```
DECLARE @result BIT
SET @result = CASE WHEN NULL <> 4 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END
PRINT @result
```

Why do i get back "1" instead of "0"

Changing it to:

```
DECLARE @result BIT
SET @result = CASE WHEN NULL IS NULL
                        OR NULL <> 4 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END
PRINT @result
```

Correctly gives me back "0"

I know NULL comparisons can be tricky, but this particular example slipped through our code review process.

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of [3 valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/). In the first case Unknown does not evaluate to true so you end up in the else

```
DECLARE @result BIT
SET @result = CASE WHEN Unknown THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END
PRINT @result
```

In the second case you are doing True or Unknown which evaluates to true.

```
DECLARE @result BIT
SET @result = CASE WHEN True
                        OR Unknown THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END
PRINT @result
```

Comment: Your code does not compile in Management Studio. Are you sure this valid T-Sql (this was a SQL 2005 specific question)? I have never seen the UNKNOWN keyword used in T-sql.

Comment: @luksan I was substituting in the truth table values in an attempt to be helpful it's not valid SQL!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the ANSI SQL standard and the behavior of comparison operators with NULL. Whenever you want to compare a value with a value that could be NULL, you need to use the IS operator to explicitly check for the case where the value could be NULL. Or you can disable the ANSI_NULLS option in SQL Server.

The following examples do what you want:

```
DECLARE @result BIT  
DECLARE @input INT

SET @input = NULL
SET @result = CASE WHEN (@input IS NULL OR @input <> 4) THEN 0  
                   ELSE 1  
              END  
PRINT @result
```

Or this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

DECLARE @result BIT 
SET @result = CASE WHEN NULL <> 4 THEN 0 
                   ELSE 1 
              END 
PRINT @result
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From a purely technical perspective, the reason why the first statement returns a 1 is because ANSI_NULLS is set to "ON" which treats NULL as "Unknown" which follows the ISO standard.

To have the values evaluate as you're expecting, run your script with `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` ahead of it.

In real life, of course, `ISNULL()` is the most awesome/safest approach.

Comment: I agree using isnull is awesome but I wouldn't call it "safe".  You have to know your underlying data types & lengths, which cuts into a lot of its worry-free-ness.  I.e., `when isnull(A.Field, 'this is a null value') = isnull(B.Field, 'this is a null value') then 1` won't return 1 if A.Field is varchar(4) and B.Field is varchar(10).  But if you pick a minimal alternative value, you may have to worry about whether it accidentally matches a real value in your tables.